# make space between square in html div?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I doing my project using Laravel 5. I take some integer value form database and create square(DIVS) in Html.This is my current out put.

[image]

You can see , space between div vertically, but horizontally they are touching each others.I want to crate same space around the squares.

This is my current div create code.

```
<section class="content">   
    <div class="box box-warning" align="center">
        <div class="gap">
            <div class="box-body" id="panel">                
                @foreach($rooms as $room)
                @if($room->roomState === 'Available')
                <div onclick="divClick('Available','{{ $room }}' );"  id='divelementone' style="width:150px;height:150px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:#00a65a;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;cursor:pointer;">{{$room->room_code}}<br/> {{$room->roomState}}</div>
                @elseif ($room->roomState === 'UnAvailable')
                <div onclick="divClick('UnAvailable', '{{ $room }}');" id='divelementtwo' style="width:150px;height:150px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:#ed5565;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;cursor:pointer;">{{$room->room_code}}<br/> {{$room->roomState}}</div>
                @elseif ($room->roomState === 'notCheckIn')
                <div onclick="divClick('notCheckIn', '{{ $room }}');" id='divelementthree' style="width:150px;height:150px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:#FFC414;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;cursor:pointer;">{{$room->room_code}}<br/> {{$room->roomState}}</div>   

                @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.box --> 
</section><!-- /.content -->
```

please , expect some expert help.

Comment: Add `padding-bottom:10px;`

Comment: @Satpal Thank you, I added this code in three divs , but still same out put.

Comment: @PranavCBalan please , can you explain where should I this code?

Comment: @uma : use `margin-bottom` for div

Comment: @PranavCBalan thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your "gap" class insert a new line

```
margin-bottom:10px;
```

Comment: I add your code , inside the div create element style sheet and my trouble is resolved.Thank you.

Comment: @uma, *Accepting answer* is a better way of saying thank you!

Answer (score 1):

its looking some standard use extenal css if you are having many common attributes it will help in debugging

```
 <style>
    .square{
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:#00a65a;
        border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;
        padding-right:10px;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin-bottom:5px;//new added property to for bottom space
        }
    </style>
    <section class="content">   
        <div class="box box-warning" align="center">
            <div class="gap">
                <div class="box-body" id="panel">                
                    @foreach($rooms as $room)
                    @if($room->roomState === 'Available')
                    <div onclick="divClick('Available','{{ $room }}' );"  id='divelementone' class="square" >{{$room->room_code}}<br/> {{$room->roomState}}</div>
                    @elseif ($room->roomState === 'UnAvailable')
                    <div onclick="divClick('UnAvailable', '{{ $room }}');" id='divelementtwo' class="square" style="background-color:#ed5565;">{{$room->room_code}}<br/> {{$room->roomState}}</div>
                    @elseif ($room->roomState === 'notCheckIn')
                  <div onclick="divClick('notCheckIn', '{{ $room }}');" id='divelementthree' class="square" style="background-color:#FFC414;">{{$room->room_code}}<br/> {{$room->roomState}}</div>   

                    @endif
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.box --> 
    </section><!-- /.content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your current padding and margin and use this in your gap class or inline:

```
padding:0 10px;
margin:2.5px; //This will give a total of 5px margin between each box. put 5 px to get a total of 10px margin.
```